# Python Calculate log(1+x)/x for x near 0

Tags: python, numerical-stability

Is there a way to correctly calculate the value of log(1+x)/x in python for values of x close to 0? When I do it normally using np.log1p(x)/x, I get 1. I somehow seem to get the correct values when I use np.log(x). Isn't log1p supposed to be more stable?

Comment: for `log(1+x)` you want `np.log1p(x)` not `np.log1p(1+x)`.

Comment: You're right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found one answer to this. I used a library called decimal.

```
from decimal import Decimal
x = Decimal('1e-13')
xp1 = Decimal(1) + x
print(xp1.ln()/x)
```

This library seems to be much more stable than numpy.

Answer (score 1):

```
np.log1p(1+x)
```

That gives you `log(2+x)`.  Change it to `np.log1p(x)`.